# Postgres - Map an ID to all objects within XML class

Tags: xml, postgresql, parsing

My question is quite similar to this: [Read XML attributes in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378577/read-xml-attributes-in-postgres), though I want each ID value mapped/bound to all of the dependable objects.

I tried to build my code based on the solution from here: [Postgresql XML-to-table with nested data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53022150/postgresql-xml-to-table-with-nested-data), because the output in this question has successfully joined product code to each barcode value.

Unfortunately, this solution didn't work in my case. Could you please take a look at my code and show what I'm doing wrong?

```
  WITH xml_data AS (
        SELECT '
    <DataObjects xmlns="http://example.com/">
    <Data>
        <Objects>
            <Attributes>
                <value>1</value>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <value>2</value>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <value>3</value>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <value>4</value>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <value>5</value>
            </Attributes>
        </Objects>
        <KeyData>
            <Key>1</Key>
        </KeyData>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Objects>
            <Attributes>
                <value>1</value>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <value>2</value>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <value>3</value>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <value>4</value>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <value>5</value>
            </Attributes>
        </Objects>
        <KeyData>
            <Key>2</Key>
        </KeyData>
    </Data> </DataObjects>'::xml
    ), keys AS (
        SELECT 
            unnest(xpath('//defns:Data/defns:KeyData/defns:Key/text()', xmlparse(document xml), array[array['defns', 'http://example.com/']]))::text as "code"
        FROM xml_data
    )
    SELECT 
        unnest(xpath('//defns:value/text()', xd.value, array[array['defns', 'http://example.com/']]))::text                    -- 4
       , ip.code
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            unnest(xpath('//defns:Data/defns:KeyData/defns:Key/text()', xmlparse(document xml), array[array['defns', 'http://example.com/']]))::text as code,     -- 2
            unnest(xpath('//defns:Data/defns:Objects/defns:Attributes', xmlparse(document xml), array[array['defns', 'http://example.com/']])) as value
        FROM xml_data
    )xd
    LEFT JOIN keys ip                                                -- 3
    ON xd.code = ip.code
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS version (SELECT * FROM version();).